# How to adjust this slider to a specific height/width

Tags: html, css, slider

I was following this tutorial on an image slide show that's responsive, I was going into the tutorial thinking I can resize the slideshow to a certain height and width the make it smaller and to fit what Idea I'm trying to do. Sadly I got stuck and can't figure out a way to do it so I came here in hopes to fix that.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do

[image]

Here is my HTML

```css
.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-container .slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
    
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide1 {
    background: url(../images/heroImage2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide2 {
    background: url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide3 {
    background: url(../images/heroImage2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide4 {
    background: url(../images/heroImage2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    20% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    25% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    45% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    50% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    70% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    75% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    95% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide slide1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide1</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide2</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide3</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide4">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Slide4</h2>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So technically you want to display 3 slide items per slide? @SmiiB

Comment: give a border to your `.slider` and see where it stands.

Comment: @fortunee I have 4 slides for each slide show and I have 3 seperate slide shows lined up horizontally for example, 3 services that a company does, each slideshow is a service

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I think what I'm looking for is a resize of the entire slideshow and not a border around it, maybe I should of explained more clearly

Comment: Yes, it was not clear what you were asking beside the demo and the sketch. it looked working somehow to me :), the container is : width:100%; turn it down to average 30% or  wrap three of them inside a flex parent ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you very much! that 30% width helped me out I think that does what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a flex container and eventually set a delay on the animation so they don't start all at the same moment.

possible example if i understood.

```css
body{margin:0;}

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 5vw;
  padding: 5vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background:lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-container .slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
  }

.slide-container  + .slide-container .slider {
animation-delay:-3.3s;
}.slide-container  +.slide-container  + .slide-container .slider {
animation-delay:-6.6s;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  right: 6px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide1 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1012/400/280);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide2 {
  background:  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1014/400/280);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide3 {
  background:  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/400/280);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.slide4 {
  background:  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1018/400/280);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide1</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide2</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide3">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide3</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide4">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide4</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide1</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide2</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide3">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide3</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide4">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide4</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide1</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide2</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide3">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide3</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide4">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Slide4</h2>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!